# C# left join two datatables

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server, datatable

I am querying a SQL server and MySQL server and then doing a left join on the resultant SQL datatable using the resultant MySQL datatable.

However, I am getting an error when trying to create the new datatable with the joined data.

These are the table structures:

```
SqlDataTable           MySqlDataTable
-------------          --------------- 
UserID, Field1         SiteUserID, Field2 
200,    12              200,       25
```

And this is my code snippet. I am getting "out of context" error for "mySqlDataRows" on the second to last line:

```
var dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof (int));
dtResult.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof (string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof (int));

var result = from sqlDataRows in sqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    join mySqlDataRows in mySqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    on sqlDataRows.Field<string>("UserID") equals mySqlDataRows.Field<string>("SiteUserID") into lj
    from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID"),
        sqlDataRows.Field<string>("Field1"),
        r == null ? 0 : mySqlDataRows.Field<int>("Field2") //The name 'mySqlDataRows' does not exist in the current context 
    }, false);
```

Comment: You may be better off doing this by hand instead of trying to be fancy and doing it all in one big LINQ statement. If you retrieve both sets of data into collections of strongly-typed objects, then loop through one of them while searching the other for a match, and combine them into a better strongly-typed collection, it would be much clearer what you're doing, and would likely perform exactly the same, since that's what LINQ is going to do behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this route because I would like to familiarize myself with LINQ and prefer the conciseness of the language in this form.

Answer (score 2):

You should select from the final joined object, which is r.

```
 var result = from sqlDataRows in sqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    join mySqlDataRows in mySqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                        on sqlDataRows.Field<string>("UserID") equals mySqlDataRows.Field<string>("SiteUserID") into lj
                    from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                    {
                        r.Field<int>("UserID"),
                        r.Field<string>("Field1"),
                        r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("Field2")
                        //The name 'mySqlDataRows' does not exist in the current context 
                    }, false);
```

The problem is that `r` contains only the columns in the mySqlDataRows table, because you use the `into` statement.
Why do you need this statement: `from r in sqlDataRows.DefaultIfEmpty()`?
I post below a code that works:

```
var result = from sqlDataRows in sqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                join mySqlDataRows in mySqlDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    on sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID") equals mySqlDataRows.Field<int>("SiteUserID")
                select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                {
                    sqlDataRows.Field<int>("UserID"),
                    sqlDataRows.Field<string>("Field1"),
                    mySqlDataRows == null ? 0 : mySqlDataRows.Field<int>("Field2")
                }, false);
```

Comment: Both of these solutions aren't working. I end up with a datatable that has zero rows, despite the fact that the sqlDataTable and mySqlDataTable are both populated with multiple rows.

Comment: And btw I need it to keep the original sqlDataTable and just add in the records from the mySqlDataTable where ever sqlDataTable.UserID == mySqlDataTable.SiteUserID